# Get Name from a lookup table (ID)

Tags: apex, salesforce-id

I'm not sure if this is allowed but I wanted to clarify something. I have a lookup table field. For the sake of an example, let's call it AccountId. I want the specific name from a specific AccountId. 
Normally, I would do it like this:

```
List<Asset> AssetList = [SELECT AccountID From Asset];
List<Account> AccountList = [Select Name FROM Account where ID IN: AssetList];
```

My question is basically can I avoid doing two Select Statements in order to get the Name from a specific ID? If I have the AccountId already, is there any way of getting just the Name from that ID without doing a select statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do it like this:

```
List AssetList = [ Select Account.Name From Asset ];
```

Instead of using AccountID use Account. Generally when you see a `[Object]ID` on standard Salesforce objects you can drop the ID and use as a relationship field, just like custom fields where you see __r.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the explanation too! Helped clear it up for me.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.